# Inequality general formula for addition and proof

Tags: inequality

If given $a,b,c,d \ge 0$ and $a \ge b$ and $c \ge d$, it seems intuitively true to me that $a + c \ge b + d$ however I cannot prove that this is true. What I have so far is that $a + c \ge b$ and $b + d \ge b$ but I cannot merge these two together. Could someone provide some tips/tricks, I do not want a full solution.
Thanks in advance and if you want to downvote please let me know what I can improve with the question! I do not post here regularly.

Comment: $a + c \ge b+c $ and $ b+c \ge b + d$, so ...

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1506435/42969

Comment: This property involving addition and order is called "translation invariance". Cf. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_ordered_group and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_group